# Redirect the form based on 3 user type which is admin,doctor and nurse

Tags: vb.net

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection`
        Dim Username As String = TextBox1.Text
        Dim Password As String = txtPassword.Text
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) Then
            ' username cannot be empty
            MsgBox("Please enter your Username!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        ElseIf Username.Contains(" ") Then
            ' username cannot have spaces
            MsgBox("Usernames can't have spaces!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) Then
            ' password cannot be empty
            MsgBox("Please enter your password!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        Else
            Conn.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=LAPTOP-M8KKSG0I;Initial Catalog=Oceania;Integrated Security=True")
            Try
                Dim sql As String = "SELECT Username, Password, Roles FROM Users WHERE Username =  '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND Password ='" & txtPassword.Text & "'"
                Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, Conn)
                cmd.Connection = Conn
                Conn.Open()
                Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
                If dr.Read = True Then
                    sql = "Select Roles FROM Users WHERE Roles = 'Admin'"
                    Me.Hide()
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Admin Page")
                    Form2.Show()
                ElseIf sql = "Select Roles FROM Users WHERE Roles = 'Doctor'" Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Doctor Page")
                    Form6.Show()
                ElseIf sql = "Select Roles FROM Users WHERE Roles = 'Nurse'" Then
                    Me.Hide()
                    MessageBox.Show("Welcome to NursePage")
                    Form4.Show()
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Eror")




                End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        End If

    End Sub
```

1. How should I solve this code?
2. I have 3 roles which is `admin`, `doctor` and `nurse`
3. In my login page I have 2 textboxes which are for username and password
4. The login button needs to validate the login
5. Different roles go to different forms. `Admin` goes to form2, `doctor` goes to form6 and `nurse` goes to form4.

Comment: What is the actual problem? You have code there that presumably doesn't do what you want but you have made no effort to explain the actual problem when you debug that code, i.e. when you set a breakpoint and step through the code, what EXACTLY does happen and how EXACTLY does that differ from your expectations? You need to provide specific details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved your validation code to a separate method because it really isn't connected to the Database code. There will come a day when you want all your database code in a separate class.

`Using...End Using` blocks ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even when there is an error.

**Always use parameters** to prevent Sql injection and make your sql easier and less error prone to write. Check you database for the actual type and size of the parameters.

Since we are only retrieving a single piece of data we can use `.ExecuteScalar` which returns an object.

Back to the User Interface code to decide which form to show.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Not ValidateInput() Then
        Return
    End If
    Dim returnValue = ValidateUserAndGetRole()
    If returnValue Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login failed")
        Return
    End If
    Dim role = returnValue.ToString
    If role = "Admin" Then
        Me.Hide()
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Admin Page")
        Form2.Show()
    ElseIf role = "Doctor" Then
        Me.Hide()
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to Doctor Page")
        Form6.Show()
    ElseIf role = "Nurse" Then
        Me.Hide()
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome to NursePage")
        Form4.Show()
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No matching role found")
    End If
End Sub


Private Function ValidateInput() As Boolean
    Dim Username As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim Password As String = txtPassword.Text
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(Username) Then
        ' username cannot be empty
        MsgBox("Please enter your Username!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        Return False
    ElseIf Username.Contains(" ") Then
        ' username cannot have spaces
        MsgBox("Usernames can't have spaces!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        Return False
    ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(Password) Then
        ' password cannot be empty
        MsgBox("Please enter your password!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Error")
        Return False
    End If
    Return True
End Function

Private Function ValidateUserAndGetRole() As Object
    Dim retVal As Object
    Using Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=LAPTOP-M8KKSG0I;Initial Catalog=Oceania;Integrated Security=True"),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT Roles FROM Users WHERE Username = @Name AND Password = @Pass;", Conn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = TextBox1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = txtPassword.Text
        Conn.Open()
        retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End Using 'closes and disposes the connection and command
    Return retVal
End Function
```

What was this

```
sql = "Select Roles FROM Users WHERE Roles = 'Admin'"
```

and this

```
sql = "Select Roles FROM Users WHERE Roles = 'Doctor'"
```

and this

```
sql = "Select Roles FROM Users WHERE Roles = 'Nurse'"
```

supposed to do? I mean, it is a nice string but it doesn't do anything.

You can add back your try catch in the database code after you have tested and please don't use an empty Catch block. It just swallows your errors and you never know what is wrong with your code.